# Refresh items in cart with every add to cart click

Tags: php, ajax, shopify, liquid, cart

I have been working on the following code, in order to make the cart update with the new items added.. The cart items is not updating automatically( items not showing up) unless I manually refresh the page. I have Attached a click event listener to the cart icon to update cart items, but that didnt worked for me. Does anybody know how to approach this...thanks a lot..

```
// Function to update the cart items inside the cart drawer
function updateCartItems(cart) {
    const cartItemsContainer = document.getElementById('cart-items-container');

    // Clear the current cart items
    while (cartItemsContainer.firstChild) {
        cartItemsContainer.removeChild(cartItemsContainer.firstChild);
    }

    // Add the updated cart items
    cart.items.forEach(item => {
        const cartItemElement = document.createElement('div');
        cartItemElement.textContent = item.title + ' - ' + item.quantity; // Customize how you want to display the items
        cartItemsContainer.appendChild(cartItemElement);
    });
}

function onQuickBuyButtonClicked(id, pro_id) {
    const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];

    $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--adding");
    const product = {
        id: id,
        quantity: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(cart) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");
                $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--added");
  //              cartRecommended(pro_id);
                
                // Update the cart items inside the cart drawer immediately
                updateCartItems(cart);
            }, 500);

            setTimeout(function() {
                document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cart:refresh', {
                    bubbles: true,
                    detail: {
                        variant: cart
                    }
                }));
            }, 1200);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding").removeClass("add-success--added");

            }, 1600);
            setTimeout(function() {
    //            $('#backdrop').addClass('backdrop_active');
            }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");

            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(errorThrown.responseText);
            $(".error_" + pro_id).html("Error: " + r.description).show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".error_" + pro_id).html("").hide(100);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

// Listen for the 'cart:refresh' event and update the cart count
document.addEventListener('cart:refresh', function() {
    $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
        const cartCount = cart.item_count || 0;
        const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];
        if (CartCount) {
            CartCount.innerHTML = cartCount;
        }
    });
});

// Attach click event listener to the cart icon to update cart items when clicked
const cartIcon = document.querySelector('.cart-icon');
if (cartIcon) {
    cartIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Fetch the cart data and update the cart items when the cart icon is clicked
        $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
            updateCartItems(cart); // Update the cart items inside the cart drawer
        });
    });
}
```